# Use Node.js command line debugger on child process?

Tags: debugging, node.js

I use the Node client debugger, like so:

> node debug myscript.js

But this process spawns a child using:

> var child = require("child_process").fork(cmd, args);

Is there a way for this child to ALSO be started in "debug" mode?

Comment: Maybe you can check inside myscript if the main process is in debug mode, and then pass `--debug` as one of the `args`.

Comment: and don't forget to change debugger port as default is already busy with parent process debugger

Comment: adding --debug, or --debug=5859 (a new port) to fork cmd or args results in errors.  I think this is because --debug is an option to the Node process, not the process that is being forked.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You have to spawn your process in a new port. There is a workaround to debug with clusters, in the same way you can do:

```
var debug = process.execArgv.indexOf('--debug') !== -1;
if(debug) {
    //Set an unused port number.
    process.execArgv.push('--debug=' + (5859));
}
var child = require("child_process").fork(cmd, args);
```

....
debugger listening on port 5859

Comment: I struggled on this because I affected the child_process module to a local variable called process, hiding the node process global variable, hence process.execArgv was not defined. Beaware "process" is a node global variable!

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem. All you need to do is to send the debugging Sig to the running process. Look at the node-inspector docs do a find for Enable debug mode

I can`t tell you how to do a debug-brk, I am not sure you can but you can always do something from code like

while(true){debugger}
So you can catch the debug statement then step out of the loop manually. Dirty I know =)

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way, this will make the child debuggable on a free port:

```
// Determine if in debug mode. 
// If so, pass in a debug-brk option manually, without specifying port.
var startOpts = {};
var isInDebugMode = typeof v8debug === 'object';
if(isInDebugMode) {
     startOpts = {execArgv: ['--debug-brk']};
}
child_process.fork('./some_module.js', startArgs, startOpts);
```

Comment: Sorry this didn't work for me, I think you need to explicitly tell it to listen on an unused port, like so execArgv.push('--debug=' + (5303 + processId++));